# Matching all values in a query for a multiValued field in SOLR

Tags: solr

I have a string multiValued field in `SOLR` named languages and I want a query to return only exact matches where all of the languages from the query are in the multiValued field.

For example, lets say I have three documents:

```
 "languages": [
          "English",
          "Russian",
          "Swedish"
        ],

"languages": [
          "English",
          "Japanese",
          "Russian",
          "Spanish",
          "Thai"
        ],

"languages": [
          "English",
          "Spanish"
        ],
```

If I were to query for *English* and *Russian* I should only return the first two documents. 
Here are some examples of the queries used:

> q=languages:"English" and languages:"Russian"
>
> q=languages:("English" and "Russian")
>
> q=languages:("English","Russian")
>
> q=languages:("Russian" "English")

In all cases these return all records that have either *English* or *Russian*. I may be overlooking something obvious but I have searched around and found nothing that explains this behavior.

Comment: How is your default requesthandler configured? You will find it within your solrconfig.xml. The tag is named `<requestHandler>` with `default=true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you write the `AND` in upper case letters. The query would look like this:

> q=languages:"English" AND languages:"Russian"

You can also use `+` or `-` to negate a part of the query. For example if you want a document which has "English" as a language but not "Russian", you would use a query like this:

> q=+languages:"English" AND -languages:"Russian"

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add `&defType=lucene` to URL which you use.

Answer (score 0):

Though this might be a late answer, it'd still be good late answer:

Firstly, "and" must be uppercase "AND".
Secondly, ("terma", "termb") and ("terma" "termb") should be same thing. The meaning of "," or " " depends on what the default operator you sepcify in schema.xml.
Thirdly, I don't think it's possible that the result is either terma or termb if you did specify AND correctly in search string.
Fourthly, if you really want either...or... result, you can specify like this: **languages:("terma" OR "termb")**.

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are good but in case you have mentioned "AND" or "OR" in your stopwords.txt file then solr will remove "AND" and "OR" from your query. We have done same thing in our project due to lots of AND and OR in data itself.

In this case you can use && (for AND) and || (for OR) as conditional parameters in your query.

Example: q=languages:"English" && "Russian"